# Angular 15 (MDC) tooltip background color (via theme)

Tags: angular-material, angular-material-15

With Angular14 I was able to define the mat-tooltips background color via

```
$theme: (
    color: (
        ...
        background: (
           ...,
            tooltip: red
        )
    )
)
@include mat.all-component-colors($theme);
```

Now a property named `color.background.tooltip` even gets generated by calling `mat.define-light-theme` but isn't applied. What has changed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the css variables:

```
.cdk-overlay-container .mat-mdc-tooltip {
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-container-color: red;
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-color: white;
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-container-shape: 4px;
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-line-height: 16px;
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-size: 12px;
  --mdc-plain-tooltip-supporting-text-weight: 400;
  --mdc-tooltip-word-break: normal;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Never the less, a native support would be appreciated ... theres an endless ticket: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26056

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I am struggling with the same problem. What you could apply as an easy fix is in your `styles.scss` is to add:

```
.mdc-tooltip__surface {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

I really do not like using `!important`, but it gets the job done in this case.

Comment: Yeah, it seams like they have a lot of issues with their move to MDC:

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26056
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/26153